# how to do multiple if statements in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, if-statement, nomethoderror

```
        <%- if @last_msg.photo? -%>
            <%= image_tag @last_msg.photo.url(:listsize) %>
        <%- else -%>
            <%= image_tag("default.jpg") %>
        <%- end -%>
```

Currently this returns either the photo from the last message or a default image, but when a new user creates an account there is no @last_msg so I get a nomethoderror. How can I put in another if statement to say that if there is no last message, then the default image will be returned? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try

```
<% if @last_msg and @last_msg.photo? -%>
```

Comment: ffs, always these last second beatings!